# Dates of arriving at the UK with a type-C multiple entry visa

Tags: visas, uk

I have received my tourist visa with as a fixed date 
from: 7/6/19    to: 7/12/19
Type: C         number of entries: Multiple      Duration of stay: 180

Issued in:: UKV102

On: 7/6/19

My simple question is that I am flying on 7/13 arriving in London 7/14/19 and return flight 8/1/19

Am I going to be ok traveling after the fixed date posted on my visa????

Thank you for the input

Comment: Are you confusing the dates (UK date style vs USA)? Your visa starts 7th June and expires on 7th Dec 2019, your flight out of the U.K. departs on 1st August? You can enter on or after 7th June; you must leave on or before 7th Dec

Comment: Dates in passports and visas are printed in day-month-year order, not American month-day-year order. Even US passports and visas use D-M-Y.

Comment: Michael, I think that was my confusion I was looking an an American month/day/year order and NOT day/month/year!!!! thank you for clarifying this !!!!

Comment: @MichaelHampton except for the MRZ, US passports and visas use letters for the month so knowing what order it is is unimportant.

Answer (score 2):

> I have received my tourist visa with as a fixed date from: 7/6/19 to: 7/12/19 Type: C number of entries: Multiple Duration of stay: 180
>
> Issued in:: UKV102
>
> On: 7/6/19

Since today is the 26th of June, we can conclude without ambiguity that the issue date of your visa, 7/6/19, is in day-month-year order, because you have the visa in your possession, meaning it was issued in the past, yet July 6th is in the future.  Your visa was issued on June 7th.

Additional evidence in support of this conclusion is that the day-month-year order [is the usual order used in the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_Kingdom).

Furthermore, a multiple-entry visa that allows a 180-day stay but has only 7 days' validity would be nonsensical.

> My simple question is that I am flying on 7/13 arriving in London 7/14/19 and return flight 8/1/19
>
> Am I going to be ok traveling after the fixed date posted on my visa????

You must travel before the date on your visa.  That date is 7 December 2019.  You must leave the UK on or before 7 December 2019 unless you obtain a different visa.

The trip you're asking about, however, is therefore fine.

Comment: thank you for your response!!! It makes sense of course!!!